# Introducing new cat (or kitten) to kitten at home

Tags: cats, behavior, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets, territory

I have recently gotten myself a cute little kitten at the start of September. I might want to get a second cat/kitten to keep her company. I've done some research about introducing new cats and read guides and tips about it. However, all the resources I found were talking about "older" cats, or cats people have owned for a quite a while already.

Do those guidelines apply in this case as well? Since my kitten at home has only been here for 1 month, I'm wondering if I might be able to just let them sniff each other through the pet carrier, and maybe have them in separate rooms for 1-2 days and do a slow, gradual introduction like that.
All the guidelines I've read said that this process usually takes weeks. While i don't have a problem with that in general, my apartment has only 2 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> rooms, so I don't really have a spare room I can keep closed for weeks.

Thanks for any inputs.

PS: If I end up getting a second cat, I plan to buy either a kitten, or a really young cat (1 year old or so).

Edit: To clarify why I'm even asking this question.
From my understanding, the problem with bringing home a new cat/kitten is that cats are very territorial, and your home is the resident's cat territory.
I was thinking that since my kitten has been in my apartment for barely 1 month, she wouldn't feel like it's her territory that "strongly" yet, so I might be able to just slowly introduce them in 1-2 days, rather than going through a few weeks long process.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.

Comment: 1 month is more than long enough for your first cat to get territorial. Unless they are both still babies, I assume the age is irrelevant to the process of introducing a new cat, but I don't have practical experience with that. I think most guides talk about introducing a kitten to an older cat because that is the most common scenario.

Comment: It's true that sometimes introducing cats can go quicker depending on the cats' personality or other factors, but I wouldn't go in assuming it will be quicker. Really rather than going by a hard, fast rule as to timeline, you should be relying on your judgement of how the cats are doing to dictate the speed. Just don't let your wishful thinking rush it, or you could end up in a bad situation.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'll be sure to follow the generally recommended guidelines when buying a new cat.